# CLR recognized threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance, clr

This page [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf749bat(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf749bat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) talks about different thread numbers reported by the CLR: Physical, Logical, and Recognized.

Can someone explain what it means for a thread to be "recognized" by the CLR?

Why would cause my recognized threads to max out at 2, while both physical and logical threads are in the 30s?

Comment: The explanation on that page is pretty clear. What don't you understand? A recognized thread is one that has an associated managed thread object. It could have been created by some other application that called into the runtime.

Comment: Yeah I didn't read it well. I read the fact that they have an associated managed object as the definition, and was confused how I could have less of these than I had logical threads.  The last sentence is the one that actually defines the group (Threads that the CLR did not create).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CLR is not necessarily aware of all threads that run inside a process.  It cannot know anything about threads that were started by native code with CreateThread().  A COM server or a native program that hosts the CLR are the common examples of that.  There are many COM servers that are wrapped by .NET classes, System.DirectoryServices and System.Management for example.

It is forced to deal with them when such a thread makes a call into managed code, an event or a callback is the usual case.  Because then it also needs to perform stack walks on that thread to find managed objects when it collects garbage or looks for CAS attributes.

At that point, this unknown native thread becomes a "recognized" thread.  There's no special significance to seeing "2" for that value, anything goes.